# GCP Authentication OAuth vs Service Accounts

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-search-console, google-iam

I need some advice on the best authentication strategy to use for an application on GCP. After reading all the documentation, I'm struggling with the correct direction to take over OAuth vs Service Accounts.

The app will allow users to connect their respective Google Search Console accounts, consenting for the app to read and collect Search Console impression data. The app will require the authentication to be long-lasting as the app will need to collect and process data daily from the day of user consent.

One option I see is to programmatically create a service account for each user and ask users to add the service account email to their respective Google Search console accounts they wish to connect to my app. The problem I see with this method is that there is a limit on 100 service accounts for a GCP project.

The other is to authenticate using OAuth and correct scopes storing the tokens and using those tokens when I need to connect to each Search Console Account. The concern I have with this approach is around how long the consent will be valid and if I will run into expiry issues.

Comment: 1) You do not need one service per user, you can use one service account for all users. The users would add the service account email address in their Google Search Console. 2) User auth. OAuth Tokens expire. You would then refresh the token using the Refresh Token. However, Refresh tokens can also expire, be invalidated, etc. They are not suitable for long term machine usage.

Comment: Are you planning on creating the app solely for one Google Workspace domain or is it an application for external people to use, meaning that the app will be available to the public.

Comment: Note: Service Accounts **are** part of OAuth too ([link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account))

Comment: Thanks this has been helpful! 

@JohnHanley - the comments around OAuth for long-term machine usage made me re-think the solution.  My only concern now is how I can maximise data security if I was to use a single service account email. Given that all my users will be using the same service account email. I guess I can manage it within my app but would be nice to give each user a dedicated service account email.

Comment: What security concern? The user is granting your service account permissions to their account, you are granting the user's account nothing. There is nothing the user can do to your account with only the service account email address.

Answer (score 1):

To give you a little insight the service account is good for impersonating domain accounts to have user-less interaction and the information obtained will be only for you. And keep in mind that a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) is used in an application that calls APIs on behalf of the user. This means that users will not even know about app movements you will perform. You only need one service account for the project and impersonate a high level access (role) user.

However, if this is for external users and you want them to see what is in it, I may recommend using the [Oauth Consent screen](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent) for authentication. This is because with your [ClientID](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials)users will authenticate as an end user and access user data in your app. And in regards the expiration of the token, you can actually request [refresh tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#:%7E:text=If%20your%20application%20needs%20access,long%20as%20they%20remain%20valid.)

internal project token can last up to 7 days whereas external project tokens can last for longer and depending on the refresh token coded.

Comment: 1) Service accounts can only be used to impersonate users in Google Workspace. The users in the question will not be from the same account. 2) Except for Domain Wide Delegation, service accounts do not make API calls on behalf of users. Service accounts are their own OAuth identity. 3) User auth does not have predictable token lifetimes for machine authorization. They can be invalidated at any time which means the user must re-authenticate.

Comment: thanks, @CizRanger - given that [refresh tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) will enevatability expire and that my app needs to maintain continuous authority to pull data I'm feeling service accounts are the way to go? My thinking around this is -  as long as the service account email is granted authority within the users Search Console account, my app will continue to authenticate. 

would be nice if I could have a dedicated service account email generated for each user, but given the limits, it seems that's not possible.

Comment: I think a service account will be best for your purpose. But if it is for domain users, you would only need to have a service account for the project to be able to impersonate an Admin user. Therefore, you will have access to the data without letting end-users know.